# Moving Opera to a new computer

Tags: opera

I am moving to a new hardware I've installed Ubuntu 16.04
I successfully moved .mozilla and .thunderbird to /home Firefox and Thundirbird work okay, very simple (from 14.04)

I installed Opera in new computer but there's no .opera at /home/user
Opera files are at /home/user/.config/opera
I moved old .opera content to that dir but Opera opens like new installation.

What am I missing?

Edit 1
[image]

As for Profile path I also copied .config/opera content to the new system.
After that, new Opera opens the same as the source.

It seems .opera at /home/user is deprecated.
I realized newest files are dated on may 22.
So I deleted home .config and Opera still opens good.

Question answered. (Posted before I saw what I then marked as the solution)

Comment: Do you use the standard Opera version (not dev or beta) on both computers?

Comment: Looking for source Opera version I also found other data. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `opera:about` shows you all the directories Opera uses so that will help narrow down what you need.

  [image]

  No matter what version (regular, dev or a beta) it will point you to the directories you need to copy.

  So `/home/USER/.config/opera` should be it. I see a bookmarks and preferences in there.

---

http://www.opera.com/nl/computer/features/sync lets you synch computers. That might be the easier method to use.

Comment: Well, I see this post after I edited my question with your help. Also .cache has been copied. Thanks.

Comment: @dstonek :D well you got me to install Opera to test this so Ill be trying it out ;-)